# Disk Migration between same model rPI

Tags: pi-2, sd-card

If I remove the SD card from an Raspberry Pi 2 and move it to another Raspberry Pi 2 (same model)

1. Can I expect it to boot correctly?
2. What modifications need to be made / considered so that the stack will work?

If you have successfully done this before, please state this in the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, doing this should work fine. I have done this many times, even switching entire OSs. There is no reason that it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I also routinely do this. In fact you can move cards between the B, B+ or Pi2 which I have.

If moving between models the only differences would be if you had drastically changed the memory map or frequency or were using a distribution (such as Ubuntu) which only supports ARM7.

If you want to use both Pi simultaneously there are a couple of other things to check:-

- `hostname` should be unique
- If you set a static IP address :-( this should also be changed.